# Can't run document.execCommand('copy); in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select and copy text from an html `<textarea>` element, but using `document.execCommand('copy');` displays an error stating that `.execCommand('copy') is not a function.`. I did also say `myTextElement.select();` before I ran the copy command. (And I am also using jQuery).

So as you know, I have a `<textarea>` element with an `id="txtMyTextElement"` tag. I also have an anchor element which has a click event which runs a function like this:

```
    $('#txtMyTextElement').select();

    let result = document.execCommand('copy');
    if (result === 'successful') {
        alert('Text copied!');
    }
    else {
        alert('Copy Failed!');
    }
```

When I click my anchor element it gives me the error: `.execCommand('copy') is not a function`. I might be missing something, but any help to fix this issue so I can copy text inside my `<textarea>` element would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a sample that reproduces the behaviour? Without one, it's going to be very hard to help you.

Comment: Check [before use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code doesn't seem to be throwing a "is not a function" error, you do have another issue.

Your issue seems to be with `=== "successful"`. This will never be `true`. Instead, `document.execCommand('copy');` returns a boolean (`true` or `false`) and so `result` will either be equal to `true` or `false`:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('#txtMyTextElement').select();
  let result = document.execCommand('copy');
  if(result) { // check if result == true 
    alert('Text copied!');
  } else {
    alert('Copy Failed!');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtMyTextElement" />
<button id="btn">Copy Text</button>
```

Comment: I suppose OP is really getting an error. The use of the clipboard can be allowed in browser options, most likely they have denied it.

Comment: @Teemu ah, good point. But wouldn't OP get a different error if it were disabled?

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I saw that you should check if the result was 'successful' or not in another question about this. But of course, it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did this solve `document.execCommand('copy') is not a function` ?? Anyway, if it worked, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @JeremyThille, check my comment.